# Interaction term with several levels in multi linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, interaction, categorical-encoding

first of all thank you very much for admitting me!

I am currently stuck with a problem regarding interaction terms:

I would like to interact a categorical variable with several levels with a continuous variable in a multi-linear regression. 
However, all of the ways I know how to do it in R failed so far.

**Can anybody help me?
Is it even possible to create such an interaction term?**

To illustrate, here is my example:

categorical variable: **acquired_years** (indicates how many years before a certain event a firm was acquired) --> categories: *not_acquired*, *acquired_one_year_before*, *acquired_two_years_before*, *acquired_three_years_before*, *acquired_four_years_and_more_before*

continuous variable: **firm_age** (age of the firm of interest)

regression model: 
y = firm_age + firm_age * acquired_one_year_before+ firm_age * acquired_two_years_before + firm age * acquired_three_years_before + firm_age * acquired_four_years_and_more_before + control_variables; omitted category: *not_acquired*

Comment: You can achieve this in two ways. The first one is to convert `acquired_years` into a factor by calling `factor(acquired_years)`. The second one is to create the regressors by hand, which is a good excercise to learn how R is dealing with factors and interactions.

Comment: Hey Michael, so you mean manually dummy coding the variables? In this case I would need k-1 dummy variables, correct? So in my case with 5 categories, I would need 4 binary dummy variables, right?

Comment: Not 100% sure I got your question, but I'd say yes. 4 binary dummies and for each of them its product with `firm_age`.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean! Thank you very much! So non_acquired would be my base category and the coefficient on firm_age would be the effect of age on y if the firm has not been acquired.

Comment: Yes. And the interaction effects will show the change in slope for the corresponding other categories. But remember, that instead of writing a lot of code, you will end up with this by writing `firm_age * factor(acquired_year)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible, and in fact I do it all the time. The result is an ANCOVA model where the regression lines are *not* parallel (i.e. you're basically fitting a new regression line of your response variable against firm_age for each level of acquired_years).

Here's an example (please excuse my silly example):

```
favourite.fruit = as.factor(c("apple","apple","orange","apple","orange"))
age = c(6,8,7,9,7)
height = c(70,80,75,90,87)
my.df = cbind.data.frame(favourite.fruit,age,height)
colnames(my.df) = c("favourite.fruit","age","height")
my.lm = lm(age ~ favourite.fruit + height + favourite.fruit * height, my.df)
my.lm
```

And the returned result:

```
Call:
lm(formula = age ~ favourite.fruit + height + favourite.fruit * 
    height, data = my.df)

Coefficients:
                 (Intercept)         favourite.fruitorange                        height  
                      -4.333                        11.333                         0.150  
favourite.fruitorange:height  
                      -0.150
```

To force the omitted category to be 'orange':

```
favourite.fruit = as.factor(c("apple","apple","orange","apple","orange"))
age = c(6,8,7,9,7)
height = c(70,80,75,90,87)
my.df = cbind.data.frame(favourite.fruit,age,height)
colnames(my.df) = c("favourite.fruit","age","height")
my.df$favourite.fruit = relevel(my.df$favourite.fruit, ref = "orange")
my.lm = lm(age ~ favourite.fruit + height + favourite.fruit * height, my.df)
my.lm
```

Results:

```
Call:
lm(formula = age ~ favourite.fruit + height + favourite.fruit * 
    height, data = my.df)

Coefficients:
                (Intercept)         favourite.fruitapple                       height  favourite.fruitapple:height  
                  7.000e+00                   -1.133e+01                    4.039e-17                    1.500e-01
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, in your model you only interact the dummy for apple with height (favourite.fruitapple:height), correct? Would it also be possible to have all interactions per category in one model? (omitting one category of course)

Comment: @Cgal Yeah, as you can see I only have two levels in my example. Since you have multiple levels in yours, the same code should give you the four terms you need.

Comment: I just had to take a little detour, now it works perfectly!

Comment: @CGal For the square of firm_age, try  poly(height,degree=2,raw=TRUE). Next time if you need to dummy code manually, consider the model.matrix function as well :)